# total lines of file using fork in c

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, pid

My code :

```
char *filename = "/home/septian/Documents/Repository.cs";
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

if (file == NULL) {
    perror("File open failed");
    return 1;
}

int num_processes = 4; // Number of child processes to create
pid_t pid[num_processes];

for (int i = 0; i < num_processes; i++) {
    pid_t child_pid = fork();

    if (child_pid < 0) {
        perror("Fork failed");
        return 1;
    } else if (child_pid == 0) {
        // This code runs in the child process
        int lines = 0;
        char ch;
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET); // Rewind the file to the beginning

        // Read the file and count lines
        while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
            if (ch == '\n') {
                lines++;
            }
        }

        **printf("Child process %d counted %d lines\n", i, lines);
        exit(lines); // Terminate the child process with the line count**
    } else {
        pid[i] = child_pid; // Store child process IDs in an array
    }
}

// This code runs in the parent process
printf("parent process\n");
int total_lines = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < num_processes; i++) {
    int status;
    waitpid(pid[i], &status, 0); // Wait for child processes to finish
    total_lines += WEXITSTATUS(status);
}

printf("Total lines in the file: %d\n", total_lines);
fclose(file);
```

when run, console show :

> parent process

> Child process 1 counted 15340 lines

> Child process 3 counted 8866 lines

> Child process 2 counted 5361 lines

> Child process 0 counted 7089 lines

> Total lines in the file: 816

Total lines not show real total lines in the file.
How to show real total lines in the file for this case use fork?

Comment: `exit` status code are a lot smaller than you need. 8 bits on Linux (I think), 16 on Windows. You'll need some other means of communication (a pipe, a file, a database, shared mem, etc)

Comment: can you give example code use other communication with fork ?

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages.  Remove the tag isn't relevant.

Comment: @Septian Ibn Yohan, Which one of the 4 ways I mentioned? What have you tried? What problem are you having?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `exit(lines)` the parent process will receive `lines & 0xFF` which is at most 255 on Linux.  When the client needs to communicate `lines` back to the parent process use a different IPC mechanism like pipe, message queue, shared memory segment (`shmget`, `shmget`), memory mapped file (mmap), socket etc.

A particular easy way to understand is for parent and child to agree on a path that the client is going to write the data, say, `lines.<pid>`.  Client can get it's own pid with `getpid()` and the server already has it from the return value of `fork()`.

Comment: If that answered your question please accept it by clicking the check mark next to the answer.